# Requested registry access is not allowed - When accessing Security Logs in Windows

Tags: vb.net, windows-server-2008-r2

I searched for existing questions concerting this, but they didn't correlate.

I written an application that scans the security event log looking for people trying to hack into the windows server and when discovered. I ban there IP in my firewall automatically. This has worked for years, then all of a sudden I start getting this error..

```
Requested registry access is not allowed
```

Here's the code

```
Dim oEventLog As New EventLog(logName:="Security", machineName:=".", source:="Microsoft Windows security auditing.")

For Each oEventLogEntry In oEventLog.Entries 'Error Happens on this line
   'Do Stuff
next
```

This runs on a Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Edition server, I can use the same code and access events in the application log, just not the security log. I'm not sure what happened, I verified the source hasn't change through change control. I'm assuming a patch was applied that is now causing this condition.

I would like to know how to work around this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it, I was running this program as a windows task. I checked the the "Run with the highest privileges" option on the schedule task and now it completes without errors. Something changed that now requires this option to be checked, when accessing the security log, I'm not sure what that is (Patch or something else).